# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webix-jet

Всем привет `webix-jet` есть такая в моделях есть такая функция

```
function onShowElement(formName){
        for (var i = 2; i<4; i++){
            $$(formName).elements["not"+i].show();
            $$(formName).elements["application"+i].show();
        }
}
```

эту функцию я возвращаю

```
return {
        showElement: onShowElement
    };
```

потом в `View` его вызываю

```
{
    view: "button",
    value: "Ишущии работу",
    click: function () {
            window.location.href = "#!/top/jobSearchForm";
            showElement.showElement('mainForm');
    }
},
```

модель и вьюшка подключены друг другу так как другие функции работают но на всякий вот подключение

```
define([
    "models/allFunction"
],function(showElement){
```

что я делаю не так??? Судя по ошибке он не может найти форму с таким `ID` хотя она есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тому коду что есть вы вызываете **onShowElement** но не передаёте ей форму **formName** , соответственно вместо данных функция **onShowElement** не получает ничего, то есть тот самый *undefined* , и естественно у него нет нужного атрибута ID.
Вызывайте **onShowElement(*сюда имя формы*)** и всё должно заработать